# Unable to display a second overlay in Chrome on button click UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I want to display a second overlay on top of a UI Dialog while processing some data when a user is clicking a "create" button.

It is working on FF, but no Chrome or IE, when i am in the debugger I can see the overlay running, but when i am not i cant see it even if the process take about 10 sec to be finished.

Here is the CSS i use :

```
#myoverlay {
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    99999;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    position:   absolute;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('images/ajax-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}

#myoverlay.ajaxloader { display: block; }
#myoverlay.hidden { display: none; }
```

The dialog is calling :

```
buttons: {
    "Create": function (event){    
var users = new Array();
    $('form[id*="add_guest_form"]').each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = name.replace(/(add_guest_form)([0-9]+)/,'\$2');
        $data = {
            //somedata set in the object
        };
        users.push($data);
    });
console.log($('#myoverlay'));                       
    $('#myoverlay').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#myoverlay').addClass('ajaxloader');
    console.log($('#myoverlay'));                       
    console.log("In dialog.");
    add2Group($('#group_name').val(),$('#group_note').val(),users),
    $(this).dialog("close");
}
```

and the function add2group is doing

```
function add2Group(name,note,users) {
       var i = 0;
       function iteration(group_id){    
          console.log("add2group: start guest " + i);      
          var uid = -1;
          //this function is not async  
          getSelectDataFromAjax(svgEditor.path() + "/guests_create.php",
           users[i],
           function (response) {
            if (response['gid']>0){         
             console.log("add2Group: Success.");
             uid = response['gid']; 
            } else {
             console.log("add2Group: Failed.");      
             $.alert("The guest is already registered or an error occured.");
            }
           }
         );
         if (uid > -1) {
          assignGroup2Guest(uid, group_id); //this function is doing ajax call, not async
           console.log("add2group: stop guest " + i);      
         }
         i++;
         if (users.length - i <= 1) {
           $('#myoverlay').removeClass("ajaxloader");
           $('#myoverlay').addClass("hidden");
           console.log("assignGroup2Guest: Last.");      
           console.log($('#myoverlay'));      
           $('#guests_list_grid').jqGrid().trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);       
         } else {
           setTimeout(iteration(group_id), 10); // Wait 10 ms to let the UI update.          
         }
       }
       console.log("In add2group.");      
       var gid = createGroup(name,note);
       if (gid > -1) {
        iteration(gid);
       }
       console.log("Out add2group.");         
};
```

I tried many other ways (use events binding doesnt work too), we looked at the problem with other developers but unable to find out a clue.
The only way we could see the overlay was to add the loooong loop in the add2group function and remove the ajax calls.

Any idea would be welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the answer to my question.

What I wanted to achieve is to of course display the overlay during the execution of the ajax calls.

However I had multiple ajax calls in my function assignGroup2Guest, and I had to wait until all of them were completed before going to the next part of the code.

2 points were wrong :

- the async option is deprecated, and was not handled by IE or Chrome when it is actually ok for FF.
- use of the completed for the callback instead of success.

then to make sure all ajax calls were correctly completed I used

```
$.when(ajax_func1(),ajax_func2()).done(function(aj1,aj2){
//do my final modifications here and release the overlay.
})
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You want the UI to update (show the overlay), and it is not doing that in time before the intensive functions you're running to create users.

Put the create/add in a timeout:

```
//This will make the overlay show until the timeout runs
setTimeout(
    function() {
         add2Group($('#group_name').val(),$('#group_note').val(),users),
         $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    1500
);
```